# error updating JScript IntelliSense warnings

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio

How can this error be rectified? What's the cause of this error?

> Warning    1   Error updating JScript IntelliSense:  Object doesn't support this property:@--

Answer (score 0):

I found this via Google - have you tried it?

http://patrickyong.net/2009/05/08/error-updating-jscript-intellisense-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-21391/

Comment: i had gone through that link but i could not get what to do